# Natural numbers symbol causes an error

Tags: symbols, errors

My latex code is `$(X_i)_{i \in \N}$` and I get this error:

```
! Undefined control sequence. of $(X_i)_{i \in \N
```

Can anybody tell me why?

I have included the `amssymb` package:

```
\usepackage{amssymb}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  I do not think that `\N` is defined.  You have to define your own symbol for that.

Comment: This confusion is caused because when you search for mathematical symbols in latex you come across this: [List of LaTeX mathematical symbols](https://oeis.org/wiki/List_of_LaTeX_mathematical_symbols) @PeterGrill

Answer (score 20):

You need to define what symbol you want to use. One option would be something like this:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand*{\field}[1]{\mathbb{#1}}%

\begin{document}
    $(X_i)_{i \in \field{N}}$ 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Using `\field` for the natural numbers seems a bit odd:)

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: Well I use it for all the number sets: Q, R, C, Z, etc.  Do you have a better name in mind?

Comment: Perhaps `\AsField` of `\blackboard`?

Comment: When you see a good answer to your question the best way to thank the author is to accept it. That adds to his or her reputation (and yours). You can vote it up, too. And you can vote up other good answers besides the one you accept.